# Break an image out of a div in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

In the example below, I have a div with a `max-width` and I'd like the image to break out of the div. Is there a simple way of achieving this in tailwind?

[image]

Comment: negative margin ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think that would work if I wanted it to break out on one side (e.g. `ml-16`) but what if I want it to break out on the left and the right?

Comment: `margin: 0 -20px` for example

Comment: Yeah just tried it — that breaks my image only to the left. But I'd like it to break out on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the **Temani Afif** example and modified it to **Tailwind** with a few change. I used the `min-width` instead of `width` and only negative `margin-left`.

```html
<section class="max-w-[60vw] p-6 mx-auto border border-black">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies tristique ante,
    lacinia elementum arcu cursus ut. Vestibulum eu diam mi. Suspendisse elit turpis, suscipit ut
    tempor aliquet, fermentum ac mauris. Donec placerat fringilla elit, eget ullamcorper massa
    accumsan condimentum. In convallis consequat massa. Aenean ultrices ante mollis, blandit ligula
    vel, bibendum velit. Nunc aliquam lorem massa. Nullam bibendum, lorem ac auctor
  </p>
  <img
    src="https://picsum.photos/id/1052/800/300"
    class="min-w-[calc(100%+140px)] ml-[-70px] py-6"
  />
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies tristique ante,
    lacinia elementum arcu cursus ut. Vestibulum eu diam mi. Suspendisse elit turpis, suscipit ut
    tempor aliquet, fermentum ac mauris. Donec placerat fringilla elit, eget ullamcorper massa
    accumsan condimentum. In convallis consequat massa. Aenean ultrices ante mollis, blandit ligula
    vel, bibendum velit. Nunc aliquam lorem massa. Nullam bibendum, lorem ac auctor
  </p>
</section>
```

[image: Edit dazziling-code]

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below:

```css
section {
  max-width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  border:1px solid;
}
img {
  margin: 0 -30px;
  width: calc(100% + 60px);
}
```

```html
<section>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies tristique ante, lacinia elementum arcu cursus ut. Vestibulum eu diam mi. Suspendisse elit turpis, suscipit ut tempor aliquet, fermentum ac mauris. Donec placerat fringilla elit, eget ullamcorper massa accumsan condimentum. In convallis consequat massa. Aenean ultrices ante mollis, blandit ligula vel, bibendum velit. Nunc aliquam lorem massa. Nullam bibendum, lorem ac auctor </p>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1052/800/300">
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur ultricies tristique ante, lacinia elementum arcu cursus ut. Vestibulum eu diam mi. Suspendisse elit turpis, suscipit ut tempor aliquet, fermentum ac mauris. Donec placerat fringilla elit, eget ullamcorper massa accumsan condimentum. In convallis consequat massa. Aenean ultrices ante mollis, blandit ligula vel, bibendum velit. Nunc aliquam lorem massa. Nullam bibendum, lorem ac auctor </p>

</section>
```

Comment: That won't work in Tailwind. Tailwind has a default setting on the img element of `max-width: 100%`. You'd have to additionally override that, or put the img in a block element and assign the negative margins to that, I think.